# Power BI Report - Add Drop-down selection Or Add Free Input Text to table row

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have just created a table in Power BI Report view (After creating my data set). I now need to create either a drop-down selection of 2 options or a text input into the table row.

> Example:

> ```
> Column 1 = Project | Column 2 = Project Name | Column 3 = Required Input Box
>     Project A      |        Best Project     |     Drop-down Selection / Free text input
> ```

Is there any way for me to accomplish this in Power BI?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I'm not looking for a Slicer/Filter. It is the actual fields I want a user to be able to select an option or text to input for a specific row in a report table - not in the data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how **PowerBI** and reporting works.
You're misunderstanding Frontend with Reporting.
Once data is imported in Direct Query / Import Mode (if you're in Desktop PowerBI) you can only transform it by using **DAX** or **M** queries, but appending data to report **dynamically** is not a feature of PowerBI.

But, you can upload an excel on **Sharepoint** and then set your dashboard data source to the sharepoint link, this could be your hack to achieve what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

There is no actual way to edit data in power bi, you may use power automate to append your data source.